# Extract time series from standardized precipitation evapotranspiration index (SPEI) R

Tags: r, database, list

Probably a simple question but I could not figure it out after several attempts. Given this example (see below) on computing SPEI at mulltiple sites, my questions are:

1) How can one plot the time series for a select site? Not all sites at once

2) How can one extract the time series for all sites from a `SPEI` object and form a dataframe? The intent is to apply principal component analysis on the time series.

```
 library(SPEI)

# Computing several time series at a time
data(balance)
names(balance)
bal_spei12 <- spei(balance,12)
plot(bal_spei12)
```

Comment: I was able to get the fitted values using `x=as.data.frame(fitted(bal_spei12))` but dates still missing

Comment: `balance` is a data.frame. And `plot(bal_spei12$fitted[ , 1])` plots the first column of the fitted values for "indore".. So what exactly is the issue? (I don't see any dates in this time series.)

Comment: @42- thanks a lot. I can now understand the output using your answer

Comment: I was able to get a data.frame of the fitted SPI as well as the dates using ```data.frame(date = zoo::yearmon(time(spi$fitted)), spi = unlist(spi$fitted))```